# Problema com comparação de tempo com mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema: Eu tenho uma tabela de períodos de entrega com tempos para cada período Ex.: Das `14:00 às 22:30` o tempo de entrega é de `40min`. Eu consigo pegar isso com um `SELECT` usando `BETWEEN`.

Quando chega em um período de entrega como `Das 22:00 às 02:00` o tempo de entrega é de `55min` o `SELECT` simples com o `BETWEEN` não está resolvendo o problema.

```
hora_inicio: 22:00
hora_fim: 02:00
tempo: 00:55
```

Vamos supor que agora seja 23:00 então fica `23:00 ENTRE 22:00 E 02:00`, só que isso não bate porque `02:00` já é do dia seguinte, certo?

A instrução SQL usada na 'parte fácil' foi:

```
SELECT tempo FROM tempo_entrega WHERE id_restaurante = 12 AND CURTIME() BETWEEN hora_inicio AND hora_fim
```

Seguindo a linha de raciocínio do @JoaoRaposo olhem só:

```
id_restaurante:12
hora_inicio: 22:00:00
hora_fim: 02:00:00
tempo: 00:40:00

id_restaurante:12
hora_inicio: 02:30:00
hora_fim: 16:30:00
tempo: 00:25:00
```

Apliquei a seguinte instrução (acredito ter adaptado corretamente no Mysql, não possuo conhecimento de IF ELSE dentro de SQL:

```
SELECT tempo FROM tempo_entrega WHERE id_restaurante = 12 AND CURTIME() BETWEEN hora_inicio AND hora_fim OR  id_restaurante = 12 AND CURTIME() BETWEEN hora_inicio AND '23:59:59' OR id_restaurante = 12 AND CURTIME() BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND hora_fim
```

E tive como retorno: `tempo: 00:25:00`

Até aí, tudo perfeito... masss... quanto eu troquei o "CURTIME()" por "23:30:00" o retorno foi:

```
tempo: 00:40:00
tempo: 00:25:00
```

Imagino, que pelo fato de eu ter usado o OR ele pegou das duas formas... mas usando o AND no lugar dos OR nao retorna nem um nem outro. :(

Comment: Poste o código que você está utilizando para dar SELECT tanto no tempo de 40min quanto no de 55min

Comment: Pode usar a data tambem? ou so' tem mesmo as horas/minutos?

Comment: O tipo utilizado para estes dois campos é `DATETIME`?

Comment: Editei ali em cima com a SQL que usei, os campos hora_inicio e hora_fim, sao do tipo TIME e eu nao uso a data nesse caso, pois isso vai valer pra qualquer dia da semana. mas aceito sugestões.

Comment: Solucao mais facil a meu ver seria separar essa entrada "22:00 ate as 02:00" em 2 entradas: 1 - "22:00 ate as 23:59:59" 2- "00:00 ate as 02:00", desse modo evitaria o problema do BETWEEN datas, senao tera que implemetar essa logica na intrucao SQL

Comment: Acho que essa vai acabar sendo a melhor forma mesmo João Raposo. A unica coisa chata vai ser ter que tratar essas entradas duplicadas para o usuário poder remover-las ou altera-las. Essa foi o principal motivo de eu ter teimado com essa forma mais 'seca'. Mas você comentou sobre implementar na instrução SQL, poderia me dar um help com isso, entendo um pouco mas não sou tão aprofundado com SQL, pela falta de tempo e necessidades especificas acabei aprendendo só o que foi preciso =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua estrutura de tabela está dificultando o trabalho, o mais correto e você trabalhar com datas inteiras e para cálculos o melhor é converter em segundos.
veja um exemplo:

```
<?php
$agora = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");//EX: 17/02/2014 19:00:24
$agora_em_segundos = strtotime($agora);//EX: 1392660273
// OU
$agora = time();//EX: 1392660273
//Entre dias
$anterior = strtotime('2014-02-16 23:30:00');//EX: 1392589800
$atual = strtotime('2014-02-17 00:25:00');//EX: 1392593100

$calculo = $atual - $anterior;//EX: 3300
$duracao = segundosParaMinutos($calculo); // 55 min

function segundosParaMinutos($seg){
    return (int)$seg / 60;
}
```

Apartir deste exemplo você pode querer alterar suas tabelas e então salvar nos campos hora_dia_inicio e hora_dia_fim em segundos.

Comment: Olá @user5418 gostei dessa forma de resolver o problema, acabei de ter algumas boas ideias com relação a isso, pois com a instrução SQL acho que não fui muito feliz, a ideia do Joao Raposo foi ótima tbm, mas creio que não consegui passar da mesma forma para a sintaxe do MySQL. Mas desse jeito, acho que vai dar boa. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que o problema está na modelagem da sua tabela. Teoricamente, deveria ser algo assim:

```
hora_dia_inicio hora_dia_fim tempo_entrega
              0             2           55
              2            22           40
             22            24           55
```

E então a query seria:

```
SELECT tempo_entrega
FROM tempo_entrega
WHERE hora BETWEEN hora_dia_inicio < ? AND hora_dia_fim >= ?;
```

Comment: Mas minha tabela é exatamente assim Rodrigo, a unica diferença é que no seu exemplo, aparentemente os campos de hora são do tipo INT, e na minha são TIME pois podem haver minutos junto as horas... da sua forma cairia no mesmo problema porque esses dados quem "cadastra" é um usuário. ou seja, um restaurante, e acho que nao seria muito usual, ele ter que cadastrar cuidando se passou da meia noite ou não, e nem o sistema bloquear isso.

Comment: Entendi. Nesse caso acredito que não haveria muita diferença pois, sendo `TIME` ou sendo `INT` a query é a mesma para ambos. Apenas no WHERE é que viraria algo do tipo `WHERE CAST('05:00:00' AS time)`.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o problema do @Stedile93 e' que nao pode estruturar a tabela dessa forma e tera' que manter "22:00 - 02:00" que e' o input do utilizador

Comment: Isso mesmo @JoaoRaposo (agora que vi como mencionar alguem no comentário). O usuário vai me informar uma hora inicial e uma hora final para aquele determinado tempo de entrega, e essa data final, pode acabar sendo do dia seguinte.

Comment: E se você tiver dois (ou mais) tempos de entrega para esse período? De qualquer forma, se o segundo valor for menor do que o primeiro (o que significa que passou da meia-noite), eu colocaria a condição de WHERE duas vezes: uma para o período das 0h às 2h, e outra para o período das 22h às 24h.